# How to tell apt-get to ignore unmet dependencies forever?

Tags: debian, apt

I use lighttpd instead of apache, but all the packages in the debian repositories are so keen on installing apache when I install a web based package. So I installed gitweb with apt-get, telling it to ignore the apache2 dependency... Now when I try to install any package, it complains about unmet dependencies.

```
root@mercury:~# apt-get install fail2ban python-central   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gitweb : Depends: apache2 or
               httpd
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@mercury:~#
```

How would I tell apt-get to ignore unmet dependencies by default?

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong :) On supprorted versions of Debian, the lighttpd package also provides the httpd virtual package which should be sufficient for gitweb.

Comment: Normally, I would install lighttpd from the repositories, but I compiled lighttpd myself so I could exclude certain modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `equivs` package.

That will let you create trivial packages that fulfill the dependency. In this case, you'll create a fake package providing httpd.

[Here is an article on how to do this task.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4610)

---

Although, as @Holger says, the best thing to do is install lighttpd from the debian repository as it provides `httpd`.